Site2Site VPN not coming up proxy identities not supported
we're pretty much clueless at this problem... maybe someone can help.
We have to configure an older Cisco 881 router via IPsec with IKEv1 as a site-2-site VPN out of necessity (new hardware won't arrive until later in the year, hopefully).
The Cisco is behind a router with NAT that has a public IP, with a local IP 10.30.10.206. (Please don't ask why :) ). It currently has the following configuration - for testing:
!
! Last configuration change at 16:53:49 UTC Tue Aug 6 2024 by user
!
version 15.0
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Testrouter
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no aaa new-model
!
!
!
memory-size iomem 10
!
!
ip source-route
!
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
license udi pid xxx
!
!
username admin privilege 15 secret 5 xxx
!
!
!
!
crypto isakmp policy 10
 encr aes 256
 authentication pre-share
 group 14
crypto isakmp key vpnkey address remote-public-ip
crypto isakmp profile VPN_PROFILE
   keyring default
   match identity address remote-public-ip 255.255.255.255
   local-address 10.30.10.206
!
!
crypto ipsec transform-set vpnset esp-aes 256 esp-sha-hmac
 mode transport
!
crypto map vpnset 10 ipsec-isakmp
 set peer remote-public-ip
 set transform-set vpnset
 set pfs group14
 set isakmp-profile VPN_PROFILE
 match address 100
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0
 !
!
interface FastEthernet1
 !
!
interface FastEthernet2
 !
!
interface FastEthernet3
 !
!
interface FastEthernet4
 description $ETH-WAN$
 ip address dhcp client-id FastEthernet4 hostname CiscoRouter
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 crypto map vpnset
 !
!
interface Vlan1
 description $ETH-SW-LAUNCH$$INTF-INFO-HWIC 4ESW$
 ip address 192.168.251.113 255.255.255.0
 ip access-group 23 in
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1452
 !
!
ip forward-protocol nd
ip http server
ip http access-class 23
ip http authentication local
ip http secure-server
!
!
ip nat inside source route-map SDM_RMAP_1 interface FastEthernet4 overload
!
ip access-list extended NAT
 deny   ip 192.168.251.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.246.0 0.0.1.255
 permit ip 192.168.250.0 0.0.0.255 any
!
access-list 23 permit 192.168.251.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 23 permit 10.30.0.0 0.0.255.255
access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.251.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.246.0 0.0.1.255
access-list 101 deny   ip 192.168.251.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.246.0 0.0.1.255
access-list 101 permit ip 192.168.251.0 0.0.0.255 any
!
!
!
!
route-map SDM_RMAP_1 permit 1
 match ip address 101
!
!
control-plane
 !
!
!
line con 0
 login local
 no modem enable
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 access-class 23 in
 privilege level 15
 login local
 transport input telnet ssh
!
scheduler max-task-time 5000
end

Phase 1 seems to comes up fine, but phase 2 does not.
Here comes the debugging output:
show crypto ipsec sa

interface: FastEthernet4
    Crypto map tag: vpnset, local addr 10.30.10.206

   protected vrf: (none)
   local  ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (192.168.251.0/255.255.255.0/0/0)
   remote ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (192.168.246.0/255.255.254.0/0/0)
   current_peer remote-public-ip port 500
     PERMIT, flags={origin_is_acl,ipsec_sa_request_sent}
    #pkts encaps: 0, #pkts encrypt: 0, #pkts digest: 0
    #pkts decaps: 0, #pkts decrypt: 0, #pkts verify: 0
    #pkts compressed: 0, #pkts decompressed: 0
    #pkts not compressed: 0, #pkts compr. failed: 0
    #pkts not decompressed: 0, #pkts decompress failed: 0
    #send errors 390, #recv errors 0

     local crypto endpt.: 10.30.10.206, remote crypto endpt.: remote-public-ip
     path mtu 1500, ip mtu 1500, ip mtu idb FastEthernet4
     current outbound spi: 0x0(0)
     PFS (Y/N): N, DH group: none

     inbound esp sas:

     inbound ah sas:

     inbound pcp sas:

     outbound esp sas:

     outbound ah sas:

     outbound pcp sas:

show crypto isakmp sa
IPv4 Crypto ISAKMP SA
dst             src             state          conn-id status
10.30.10.206    remote-public-ip   QM_IDLE           2131 ACTIVE
remote-public-ip   10.30.10.206    MM_KEY_EXCH       2009 ACTIVE
remote-public-ip   10.30.10.206    MM_KEY_EXCH       2008 ACTIVE
remote-public-ip   10.30.10.206    MM_NO_STATE       2007 ACTIVE (deleted)

IPv6 Crypto ISAKMP SA

And finally
debug crypto isakmp
Crypto ISAKMP debugging is on
Testrouter#
*Aug  6 17:09:35.950: ISAKMP:(2131):purging node 1585591225
*Aug  6 17:09:36.314: ISAKMP (2131): received packet from remote-public-ip dport 4500 sport 36750 Global (R) QM_IDLE
*Aug  6 17:09:36.314: ISAKMP: set new node -1523865904 to QM_IDLE
*Aug  6 17:09:36.318: ISAKMP:(2131): processing HASH payload. message ID = -1523865904
*Aug  6 17:09:36.318: ISAKMP:(2131): processing SA payload. message ID = -1523865904
*Aug  6 17:09:36.318: ISAKMP:(2131):Checking IPSec proposal 1
*Aug  6 17:09:36.318: ISAKMP: transform 1, ESP_AES
*Aug  6 17:09:36.318: ISAKMP:   attributes in transform:
*Aug  6 17:09:36.318: ISAKMP:      key length is 256
*Aug  6 17:09:36.318: ISAKMP:      authenticator is HMAC-SHA
*Aug  6 17:09:36.318: ISAKMP:      group is 14
*Aug  6 17:09:36.318: ISAKMP:      encaps is 3 (Tunnel-UDP)
*Aug  6 17:09:36.318: ISAKMP:      SA life type in seconds
*Aug  6 17:09:36.318: ISAKMP:      SA life duration (basic) of 3600
*Aug  6 17:09:36.318: ISAKMP:(2131):atts are acceptable.
*Aug  6 17:09:36.318: ISAKMP:(2131): IPSec policy invalidated proposal with error 32
*Aug  6 17:09:36.318: ISAKMP:(2131): phase 2 SA policy not acceptable! (local 10.30.10.206 remote remote-public-ip)
*Aug  6 17:09:36.318: ISAKMP: set new node -311790503 to QM_IDLE
*Aug  6 17:09:36.318: ISAKMP:(2131):Sending NOTIFY PROPOSAL_NOT_CHOSEN protocol 3
        spi 2234313256, message ID = -311790503
*Aug  6 17:09:36.318: ISAKMP:(2131): sending packet to remote-public-ip my_port 4500 peer_port 36750 (R) QM_IDLE
*Aug  6 17:09:36.318: ISAKMP:(2131):Sending an IKE IPv4 Packet.
*Aug  6 17:09:36.318: ISAKMP:(2131):purging node -311790503
*Aug  6 17:09:36.318: ISAKMP:(2131):deleting node -1523865904 error TRUE reason "QM rejected"
*Aug  6 17:09:36.318: ISAKMP:(2131):Node -1523865904, Input = IKE_MESG_FROM_PEER, IKE_QM_EXCH
*Aug  6 17:09:36.318: ISAKMP:(2131):Old State = IKE_QM_READY  New State = IKE_QM_READY
*Aug  6 17:09:37.206: ISAKMP:(0): SA request profile is VPN_PROFILE
*Aug  6 17:09:37.206: ISAKMP: Created a peer struct for remote-public-ip, peer port 500
*Aug  6 17:09:37.206: ISAKMP: New peer created peer = 0x86A2BA2C peer_handle = 0x8000013F
*Aug  6 17:09:37.206: ISAKMP: Locking peer struct 0x86A2BA2C, refcount 1 for isakmp_initiator
*Aug  6 17:09:37.206: ISAKMP: local port 500, remote port 500
*Aug  6 17:09:37.206: ISAKMP: set new node 0 to QM_IDLE
*Aug  6 17:09:37.206: ISAKMP: Find a dup sa in the avl tree during calling isadb_insert sa = 85EED290
*Aug  6 17:09:37.206: ISAKMP:(0):Can not start Aggressive mode, trying Main mode.
*Aug  6 17:09:37.206: ISAKMP:(0):Found ADDRESS key in keyring default
*Aug  6 17:09:37.206: ISAKMP:(0): constructed NAT-T vendor-rfc3947 ID
*Aug  6 17:09:37.206: ISAKMP:undbu(0): constructed NAT-T vendor-07 ID
*Aug  6 17:09:37.206: ISAKMP:(0): constructed NAT-T vendor-03 ID
*Aug  6 17:09:37.206: ISAKMP:(0): constructed NAT-T vendor-02 ID
*Aug  6 17:09:37.206: ISAKMP:(0):Input = IKE_MESG_FROM_IPSEC, IKE_SA_REQ_MM
*Aug  6 17:09:37.206: ISAKMP:(0):Old State = IKE_READY  New State = IKE_I_MM1

*Aug  6 17:09:37.206: ISAKMP:(0): beginning Main Mode exchange
*Aug  6 17:09:37.206: ISAKMP:(0): sending packet to remote-public-ip my_port 500 peer_port 500 (I) MM_NO_STATE
*Aug  6 17:09:37.206: ISAKMP:(0):Sending an IKE IPv4 Packet.
*Aug  6 17:09:37.242: ISAKMP (0): received packet from remote-public-ip dport 500 sport 500 Global (I) MM_NO_STATE
*Aug  6 17:09:37.242: ISAKMP:(0):Input = IKE_MESG_FROM_PEER, IKE_MM_EXCH
*Aug  6 17:09:37.242: ISAKMP:(0):Old State = IKE_I_MM1  New State = IKE_I_MM2

*Aug  6 17:09:37.242: ISP:(0): processing SA payload. message ID = 0
*Aug  6 17:09:37.242: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload
*Aug  6 17:09:37.242: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 215 mismatch
*Aug  6 17:09:37.242: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID is XAUTH
*Aug  6 17:09:37.242: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload
*Aug  6 17:09:37.242: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID is DPD
*Aug  6 17:09:37.242: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload
*Aug  6 17:09:37.242: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 69 mismatch
*Aug  6 17:09:37.242: ISAKMP (0): vendor ID is NAT-T RFC 3947
*Aug  6 17:09:37.242: ISAKMP:(0):Found ADDRESS key in keyring default
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:(0): local preshared key found
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP : Looking for xauth in profile VPN_PROFILE
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:(0):Checking ISAKMP transform 1 against priority 10 policy
*unedg  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:      encryption AES-CBC
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:      keylength of 256
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:      hash SHA
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:      default group 14
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:      auth pre-share
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:      life type in seconds
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:      life duration (VPI) of  0x0 0x1 0x51 0x80
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:(0):atts are acceptable. Next payload is 0
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:(0):Acceptable atts:actual life: 0
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:(0):Acceptable atts:life: 0
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:(0):Fill atts in sa vpi_length:4
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:(0):Fill atts in sa life_in_seconds:86400
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:(0):Returning Actual lifetime: 86400
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:(0)::Started lifetime timer: 86400.
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 215 mismatch
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID is XAUTH
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID is DPD
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:(0): processing vendor id payload
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:(0): vendor ID seems Unity/DPD but major 69 mismatch
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP (0): vendor ID is NAT-T RFC 3947
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:(0):Input = IKE_MESG_INTERNAL, IKE_PROCESS_MAIN_MODE
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:(0):Old State = IKE_I_MM2  New State = IKE_I_MM2

*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:(0): sending packet to remote-public-ip my_port 500 peer_port 500 (I) MM_SA_SETUP
undebug 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:(0):Sending an IKE IPv4 Packet.
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:(0):Input = IKE_MESG_INTERNAL, IKE_PROCESS_COMPLETE
*Aug  6 17:09:37.246: ISAKMP:(0):Old State = IKE_I_MM2  New State = IKE_I_MM3

*Aug  6 17:09:37.314: ISAKMP (0): received packet from remote-public-ip dport 500 sport 500 Global (I) MM_SA_SETUP
*Aug  6 17:09:37.314: ISAKMP:(0):Input = IKE_MESG_FROM_PEER, IKE_MM_EXCH
*Aug  6 17:09:37.314: ISAKMP:(0):Old State = IKE_I_MM3  New State = IKE_I_MM4

*Aug  6 17:09:37.314: ISAKMP:(0): processing KE payload. message ID = 0
*Aug  6 17:09:37.506: ISAKMP:(0): processing NONCE payload. message ID = 0
*Aug  6 17:09:37.506: ISAKMP:(0):Found ADDRESS key in keyring default
*Aug  6 17:09:37.506: ISAKMP:received payload type 20
*Aug  6 17:09:37.506: ISAKMP (2015): NAT found, both nodes inside NAT

The other site is a StrongSwan-based server with the config
# For IPsec tunnel (site-to-site) tunnelname
#
conn tunnelname

  ## basics ##
  auto=start
  authby=secret
  type=tunnel

  ## timeouts ##
  dpdaction=restart
  dpddelay=30s
  dpdtimeout=120s

  ## connection data ##
  left=10.1.99.2
  right=cisco-public-ip
  mark_in=0x02000000/0xfe000000
  mark_out=0x02000000/0xfe000000

  ## routing ##
  leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
  rightsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
  fragmentation=yes
  compress=no

  ## phase 1 (IKE) ##
  leftid=remote-public-ip
  rightid=10.30.10.206
  keyexchange=ikev1
  aggressive=no
  ike=aes256-sha1-modp2048!
  reauth=yes
  ikelifetime=86400s

  ## phase 2 (ESP) ##
  leftid2=remote-public-ip
  rightid2=10.30.10.206
  esp=aes256-sha1-modp2048!
  rekey=yes
  keylife=3600s
  keyingtries=%forever
  forceencaps=no

it's giving the following output
2024-08-06T20:57:01+02:00 primary ubios-udapi-server[1347949]: 13[ENC] generating QUICK_MODE request 3510648990 [ HASH SA No KE ID ID ]
2024-08-06T20:57:01+02:00 primary charon-custom[1347949]: 13[ENC] generating QUICK_MODE request 3510648990 [ HASH SA No KE ID ID ]
2024-08-06T20:57:01+02:00 primary ubios-udapi-server[1347949]: 13[IKE] next IV for MID 3510648990 => 16 bytes @ 0x7f80019140
2024-08-06T20:57:01+02:00 primary ubios-udapi-server[1347949]: 13[IKE]    0: 43 09 2C 98 28 F0 21 CC 56 65 3A D3 19 AF 31 4B  C.,.(.!.Ve:...1K
2024-08-06T20:57:01+02:00 primary ubios-udapi-server[1347949]: 13[IKE] next IV for MID 3510648990 => 16 bytes @ 0x7f78002dd0
2024-08-06T20:57:01+02:00 primary ubios-udapi-server[1347949]: 13[IKE]    0: 32 79 CA D9 2A 43 77 73 5A A6 78 3D 03 18 0B EE  2y..*CwsZ.x=....
2024-08-06T20:57:01+02:00 primary ubios-udapi-server[1347949]: 13[NET] sending packet: from 10.1.99.2[4500] to cisco-wan-ip[4500] (444 bytes)
2024-08-06T20:57:01+02:00 primary charon-custom[1347949]: 13[NET] sending packet: from 10.1.99.2[4500] to cisco-wan-ip[4500] (444 bytes)
2024-08-06T20:57:01+02:00 primary ubios-udapi-server[1347949]: 09[NET] received packet: from cisco-wan-ip[4500] to 10.1.99.2[4500] (92 bytes)
2024-08-06T20:57:01+02:00 primary charon-custom[1347949]: 09[NET] received packet: from cisco-wan-ip[4500] to 10.1.99.2[4500] (92 bytes)
2024-08-06T20:57:01+02:00 primary ubios-udapi-server[1347949]: 09[IKE] next IV for MID 40853575 => 16 bytes @ 0x7f6c002c90
2024-08-06T20:57:01+02:00 primary ubios-udapi-server[1347949]: 09[IKE]    0: 3E AD 44 F1 14 16 66 AD 62 BB 45 95 80 F1 82 42  >.D...f.b.E....B
2024-08-06T20:57:01+02:00 primary ubios-udapi-server[1347949]: 09[ENC] parsed INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 40853575 [ HASH N(NO_PROP) ]
2024-08-06T20:57:01+02:00 primary ubios-udapi-server[1347949]: 09[IKE] Hash => 20 bytes @ 0x7f6c006030
2024-08-06T20:57:01+02:00 primary ubios-udapi-server[1347949]: 09[IKE]    0: 19 89 03 00 B6 CD A3 19 1B 21 9E D8 0F 56 1F 24  .........!...V.$
2024-08-06T20:57:01+02:00 primary ubios-udapi-server[1347949]: 09[IKE]   16: 0F 0E DD D8                                      ....
2024-08-06T20:57:01+02:00 primary charon-custom[1347949]: 09[ENC] parsed INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 40853575 [ HASH N(NO_PROP) ]
2024-08-06T20:57:01+02:00 primary ubios-udapi-server[1347949]: 09[IKE] received NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN error notify
2024-08-06T20:57:01+02:00 primary ubios-udapi-server[1347949]: 09[KNL] deleting SAD entry with SPI cdead044

Any ideas? (Despite using SHA512 and so on...)?
Is it maybe because of
  ## routing ##
  leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
  rightsubnet=0.0.0.0/0

Thank you very much in advance!

You need to turn on NAT-T - port forwarding breaks native IKE.

Do not NAT. There is not reason with differing private addressing. It sounds like you are behind an ISP CGN, which means you are probably using a residential account rather than a business account. A proper business account gives you a public address.

Thank you very much! I will check it out in the coming days.
